# how to creat dynamic table using pdfkit

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code :

```
doc.table([
  ["cell11","cell21","cell31"],
  ["cell12","cell22","cell32"]`
  ["cell13","cell23","cell33"]
  ],{
    width:20,
    height:40,
    x:30,
    y:40
});
```

Get error doc.table is not a function.

Comment: Add your complete code to get proper reference.

Comment: I think you did not include your module properly.

Comment: included pdfkit module. doc.text() is working

Comment: There is a ` is added in 2nd array

Comment: remove extra character

Comment: Even I did not able to find method doc.table()

Comment: still not working. same issue again

Comment: how to add table using pdfkit module

Comment: https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/issues/29

Comment: Theres is an alternate option is : https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

Comment: I copied code from here -- github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/issues/29

Comment: But they have add code described in the above post

Comment: Please read question carefully

Comment: put a comma (,) at the end of   
     ["cell12","cell22","cell32"] and remove => "`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use voilab-pdf-table npm module and add plugin voilab-pdf-table/plugins/fitcolumn to create table.